# API endpoint receives request but nothing happens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, post, endpoint

I'm setting up an API for my Rails app, and I'm trying to receive POST requests from other apps. I've managed to *send* a Post request remotely from a different app, but nothing happens in the method that receives the request.

Here's my Heroku logs, showing that the request was received:

> 2018-05-13T04:55:54.456743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/path" host=www.example.com request_id=e0adgss69-0fbd-4597-8fse-f40d344c55f fwd="xx.xx.xxx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=367ms status=422 bytes=93468 protocol=http

Here's the code in the other app that sends the request:

```
  @items = []
  post_url = "http://www.example.com/path"
  post_uri = URI(post_url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(post_uri.host, post_uri.port)
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(post_uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
  req.body = {items: @items}.to_json
  res = http.request(req)
  puts "response #{res.body}"
```

And here's my method that receives the request:

```
def path
  Item.create(name: "test")
end
```

But after the request is sent, my first app has no Item named "test". But I know the request has been received. When I run `Item.create(name: "test")` in my console, it succeeds. What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure your `path` method is getting executed? Have you checked for errors on the `Item.create` call?

Comment: check server production logs for more info on what is going on

Comment: @muistooshort My `path` method is apparently not being executed, because running `Item.create(name: "test")` in console works fine. I don't understand why it's not being executed, because my logs show that the post request was received.

Comment: @MartinZinovsky The line I listed from my Heroku logs is the only feedback given in the logs.

Comment: @YuriGert I mean rails app production logs in `rails_root/log/production.log`

Comment: What do your routes look like? Have you tried adding some error checking to your controller? What response do you get back?

Comment: You can check your code in rails console. `rails c` then step by step reproduce your code that sends a request.

Answer (score 0):

Note the `422` status code returned in your logs. This means that `Item.create` failed.

Things to try / investigate:

1. Are there permissions that are stopping the request or limiting what objects the user is allowed to work with? e.g. check CanCan configuration, if you're using it or a similar gem.
2. Try using `create!` in the console rather than `create`. Does it raise an error? There might be validation or additional required fields.
3. Change your production logging to debug level, or assign the creation to a variable `item` and then log out `item.errors.full_messages`